# Access violation reading location in class

Tags: c++, memory, runtime-error

I am quite new to C++ and I have been playing around with
pointers and classes a bit. I have run into a problem that so far
I haven't been able to find a solution to:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77F87508 (msvcr110d.dll) in RAII.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCC0.

It seems to have something to do with me accessing a pointer
that I don't have access to.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "Example.hpp"

void example()
{
    Example e;
}

int main()
{
    example();
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Example.cpp:

```
#include "Example.hpp"

Example::Example()
{
    m_a = new int(1);
    m_b = new int(2);
    m_b = new int(3);
}

Example::~Example()
{
    delete m_a;
    delete m_b;
    delete m_c;
}
```

Example.hpp:

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLE_HPP_
#define _EXAMPLE_HPP_

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
private:
    int *m_a;
    int *m_b;
    int *m_c;
public:
    Example();
    ~Example();
};

#endif _EXAMPLE_HPP_
```

So, what I basically do is allocate memory in the 
constructor and deallocate it in the destructor.

Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance :D

Comment: `_EXAMPLE_HPP_` is a [bad choice of identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: What would a good choice be for an identifier?

Comment: I usually use `PROJECTNAME_FILENAME_EXTENSION`. With some variation of that, I see a trailing `_` or `_DEFINED` pretty commonly as well.

Comment: Some editors also have tools for adding the the definition from the guid of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code:

```
Example::Example()
{
    m_a = new int(1);
    m_b = new int(2);
    m_b = new int(3); // <--- you probably meant it to be m_c
}
```

For that reason when you call `delete m_c;` in destructor you end up freeing the memory which does not belong to your application, hence experience the crash.

Comment: I have no idea on how I missed this!
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @0x499602D2, I was so focused on trying to find where it was being copied/moved, so as to be a Rule of N thing.